# Duplication of Collections

Tags: animation, modifiers, linked-data, collections

According to the tutorial [*"Step by step creating a flock of low poly birds in Blender"*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSL98LLr1kw) I created a flock of crows.

[image]

The flock has in its structure a *System of Particles*, armatures, animations, modifiers.

[image]

Now I need to have nine independent flocks of crows in one scene. I need to set a unique behavior for each flock (for example, add a *Build* modifier).

I'm doing **'Duplicate Collection'** (Crows_Flock) in *Outliner*. At the same time, the collections remain linked. Changing the settings of one leads to changing the settings in the other collection.

How to properly copy a given collection so that each of them is detached from the others?

Blender version 3.6.2.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148278/discussion-on-question-by---duplication-of-collections); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still couldn't see the animation keys for the "**Build**" modifier. I had to add a flock of crows to the scene from the source file nine times using the *Copy Objects* - *Paste Objects* method. Although this method has a number of disadvantages (loss of scale, loss of the structure of directory collections), it provides completely independent instances of objects. The final render of this scene can be seen at the link: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/eyPfUWDr7xw